# How to disable Google Ads two-step authentication

Tags: google-ads, authentication, smtp

I currently am using my Gmail for SMTP for my site. But I also signed up for Google Ads. To sign into Google Ads, I have to two-step authenticate. But because of this, it disables the SMTP for my website.

I would like to keep my SMTP as is. How do I disable the two-step authentication? I am familiar with toggling it on and off by going to `https://myaccount.google.com/security` but that means one will always be disabled.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible.  Can you sign up for a separate Google account for ads?  Or find a new SMTP provider?